# JSoup doesn't give the desired results

Tags: jsoup

This is my code:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PageReaderBisnis {
public void start(){
    try {
        String url = "http://finansial.bisnis.com/";
        print("Fetching %s...", url);

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        Elements select = doc.select("div.post-category-item");
        Elements tautan =  select.select("h2>a");
        print("\nLinks: (%d)", tautan.size());
        for (Element link: tautan){
            String t = link.attr("abs:href");
            print(" * a: <%s>", t);
        }
        print("\nNama: (%d)", tautan.size());
        for (Element link: tautan){
            String t = link.text();
            print(" * a: %s", t);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("No connection");
    }
}

private static void print(String msg, Object... args){
    System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
}

private static String trim(String s, int width){
    if(s.length() > width){
        return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
    }
    else return s;
}
}
```

And the website is finansial.bisnis.com

I am hoping to print:

Links: (10)

- a: http://finansial.bisnis.com/read/20140819/9/251157/rapbn-2015-pertumbuhan-ekonomi-56-berat-dicapai

...

- a: http://finansial.bisnis.com/read/20140819/9/251110/defisit-anggaran-pemangkasan-kementerian-bakal-terulang

Nama: (10)

- a: RAPBN 2015: Pertumbuhan Ekonomi 5,6% Berat Dicapai
- a: BI Musnahkan Uang Tidak Layak Edar Rp22,6 Triliun Kuartal II/2014
- a: DAU 2015 Dirancang Naik Jadi Rp349,2 Triliun. Ini Penyebabnya
- a: Pemerintah Diminta Tunda DAU Pemda yang Dananya Nganggur
- a: Kredit Manufaktur dan Perdagangan Kian Melambat
- a: BCA Tidak Naikkan Bunga KPR Hingga Akhir Tahun
- a: BI Prediksikan Suku Bunga Meningkat Semester II/2014
- a: Bank Victoria: Genjot Pendapatan Non Bunga, VIP Maxima Link Diluncurkan
- a: Semester I, Belanja Daerah Terserap 31,3%
- a: Defisit Anggaran: Pemangkasan Kementerian Bakal Terulang?

I was writing the code and hoping for the result to come out just as I want but it doesn't seem it give the correct result. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: sorry for late reply. i didn't try your solution because i agreed with you that the server messes up. i'm just doing it the hard way and replace the mobile version's substring with the original substring. i guess it's kinda manual but that's all i could do for the time being. thanks for your answer anyway. :)

Comment: The fact that the server answers with the mobile version is due to no providing the userAgent header. If you had tried the userAgent the server would recognize you as a pc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")  
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get();
```

The server either doesn't allow bots, or it messes up and shows you the mobile version.